# Changing the Accept header for a session with Chrome

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome, headers

If I want to change the user agent string for an entire session, I can start Chrome from the command line with the user agent switch, e.g.

```
open ~/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args -user-agent="STRING"
```

and every request will use that string with no further input needed from me. I want to do something similar with the Accept header. There are extensions out there that do this per request and per tab/domain, but I want this done blanket fashion for an entire *browsing* session (not HTTP session).

Is there a way? I found [a list of Chromium command line switches, but none appear to help with this](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use EditThisCookie chrome extension
for more info  see : 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en

Comment: I don't see a way to edit headers with that extension, only cookies. I was referring to *browsing* sessions, not HTTP sessions.